# How do I put a text on top of the hat?

Tags: typography

This is what I'm trying to do:

[image]

I basically want to put a hat on top of the word and then a text on top of the hat. How do I do this?

Comment: Do you looking this `$\stackrel{text}{\wedge}$`? Sorry, if it not suits...

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "hat". Presumably not a bowler hat or a top hat, right? Could it be a curly brace lying on its side?

Comment: @Mico you are right, I need something that looks like the line (with borders) on the picture I attached. I called it a "hat" because I didn't find a better name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hope the below can meets your requirement:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mnsymbol}
\begin{document}

$\overlinesegment{text}$

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: `fdsymbol.sty` also does the same trick...

Answer (score 15):

With standard fonts and `stmaryrd`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd} % for the \mapsfrom glyph
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \arrowfill@

\newcommand{\overhat}[2]{% #1 = main word, #2 = label
  \leavevmode\vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      \footnotesize\strut\,#2\,\cr
      \makehat\cr
      \strut#1\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\makehat}{%
  \arrowfill@{\mapstochar\relbar}\relbar{\relbar\mapsfromchar}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Hello, \overhat{Jeffrey}{name}

Hello, \overhat{A}{y}

Hello, \overhat{A}{zzz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without fonts, so the size of the bars are easily customizable. Here the height is 1pt.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\newcommand{\overhat}[2]{% #1 = main word, #2 = label
  \leavevmode\vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      \footnotesize\strut\,#2\,\cr
      \hatbar
      \leaders\hrule height 0.9pt depth -0.5pt\hfill
      \hatbar\cr
      \strut#1\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\hatbar}
 {
  \draw_begin:
  \draw_cap_round:
  \draw_path_moveto:n {0pt,0pt}
  \draw_path_lineto:n {0pt,1pt}
  \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
  \draw_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Hello, \overhat{Jeffrey}{name}

Hello, \overhat{A}{y}

Hello, \overhat{A}{zzz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Such a nice suggestion...

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if I understood your formatting objective, but the `\overbracket` directive of the mathtools package may be what you're looking for.

[image]

Observe that `\overbracket` is a math-mode command; hence the `$` symbols to initiate and terminate inline math mode and the two instances of `\text` in

```
$\overbracket{\text{Jeffrey}}^{\text{name}}$
```

If your document has several instances of such `\overbracket`-based directives, it's probably worth setting up a dedicated macro to help simplify and streamline entering the required information. E.g.,

```
\newcommand\myhat[2]{$\overbracket{\text{#1}}^{\text{#2}}$
```

This would allow you to input `\myhat{Jeffrey}{name}`.

Section 3.2.2 of the user guide of the mathtools package provides information on customizing (a) the line thickness of the "hat" and (b) the height of the hat above the baseline.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\overbracket' macro
\begin{document}
\sffamily % optional

Hello, $\overbracket{\text{Jeffrey}}^{\text{name}}$!
\end{document}
```